# How to convert list to binary tree without recursion

Tags: javascript, list, tree

As an exercise I am trying to convert a list to a binary tree without using recursion.

This is basically where I get stuck.

```
var items = [
  { a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 }, { a: 20 }, { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 }, { a: 30 }, { a: 300 }, { a: 40 }, { a: 4 }
]

var top = {}

for (var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i+=2) {
  var a = items[i]
  var b = items[i + 1]

  top.left = { data: a }
  top.right = { data: b }

  top = top.right
}
```

The `top = top.right` is obviously not correct, and it makes it so only one branch of the expanding tree gets created, so it's basically just a linked list with a little bud of a leaf at each level.

```
    /\
     /\
      /\
       /\
        /\
          \
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how to go down *all* branches of the tree *and* put the nodes in an order in the binary tree where they can be iterated over / traversed in the original order they were in the list. I'm not sure what this is called, if I should be doing some version of DFS/BFS inorder/preorder/postorder, I'm not too sure. Wondering if one could demonstrate in JS how this could be done.

I'm not sure what the output even should be, but if I had to guess it would be like this:

```
             top
       1             10
  100     20      2      3
30  300  40 4
```

Comment: You need to iterate over every element of  the array, not every two of them. The children of every node, on the contrary, are to be found in position 2i and 2i+1

Comment: Can you please show the expected output object?

Comment: I am not too sure what the expected output is, that's part of the question :) I'd like to get it into a form where it can regenerate the list from the tree, but don't know how that looks.

Comment: @MaheerAli okay added a guess.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use recursion?

Comment: Yes there's many reasons, performance, large trees, and learning experience.

Comment: Recursion is not a performance bottleneck, even for large trees.

Comment: why do you not have a top node with a value?

Comment: I don't know, please correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing we need to decide is the structure of our tree. Instead of having a separate root node, it'd make sense for the first element of the list to be the root. Hence, our tree data structure could be defined as follows:

```js
// A Tree(a) is one of:
// - null
// - tree(a, Tree(a), Tree(a))
const tree = (value, left, right) => ({ value, left, right });
```

Hence, our output tree will look like:

```
                                 1
                                 |
                    +------------+------------+
                    |                         |
                    10                       100
                    |                         |
          +---------+---------+         +-----+-----+
          |                   |         |           |
          20                  2         3           30
          |                   |         |           |
    +-----+-----+           +-+-+    +--+--+     +--+--+
    |           |           |   |    |     |     |     |
   300          40          4  null null  null  null  null
    |           |           |
 +--+--+     +--+--+     +--+--+
 |     |     |     |     |     |
null  null  null  null  null  null
```

If we were to use recursion, then the code is straightforward because trees are recursive data structures:

```js
const buildTree = (xs, i = 0) => i >= xs.length ? null :
    tree(xs[i], buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 1), buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 2));
```

Putting it all together:

```js
// A Tree(a) is one of:
// - null
// - tree(a, Tree(a), Tree(a))
const tree = (value, left, right) => ({ value, left, right });    

const buildTree = (xs, i = 0) => i >= xs.length ? null :
    tree(xs[i], buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 1), buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 2));

console.log(buildTree([1, 10, 100, 20, 2, 3, 30, 300, 40, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to convert this recursive program into an iterative program.

---

Here's an algorithmic method of converting any recursive function into an iterative function. First, convert the function into continuation-passing style:

```
const buildTree = (xs, i = 0, k = x => x) => i >= xs.length ? k(null) :
    buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 1, left =>
    buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 2, right =>
    k(tree(xs[i], left, right))));
```

Next, replace the continuations with a data structure which contains all the necessary free variables of the continuation. Also, replace the continuation calls with an application to a function `applyCont` which contains the logic of the continuations:

```js
const buildTree = (xs, i, k = null) => i >= xs.length ? applyCont(k, null) :
    buildTree(xs, 2 * i + 1, { xs, i, k });

const applyCont = (k, x) => k === null ? x :
    !k.hasOwnProperty("x") ? buildTree(k.xs, 2 * k.i + 2, { x, xs: k.xs, i: k.i, k: k.k }) :
    applyCont(k.k, tree(k.xs[k.i], k.x, x));
```

If you notice, the structure of the continuations is now similar to a linked list. In fact, you can think of the continuations as a stack of frames (i.e. the program stack). Now, it's easy to convert this recursive code into iterative code as follows:

```
const buildTree = xs => {
    var i = 0, stack = null;

    loop: do {
        while (i < xs.length) {
            i = 2 * i + 1;
            k = { i, k };
        }

        var x = null;

        while (k) {
            if (!k.hasOwnProperty("x")) {
                i = 2 * k.i + 2;
                k.x = x;
                continue loop;
            }

            k = k.k;
            x = tree(k.xs[k.i], k.x, x);
        }

        return x;
    } while (true);
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, was able to create an iterative one after this, posted below.

Comment: Q: _"How to convert list to binary tree without recursion"_
A: _"I'll leave it as an exercise for you to convert this recursive program into an iterative program"_
XD

Answer (score 2):

You could use two indices, one for the **node** list and the other for the **target** list. Then, put the next two nodes on the left and right side of the **target** node.

Proceed until no more node is available.

This tree has no empty start node.

```js
var items = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 }, { a: 20 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 30 }, { a: 300 }, { a: 40 }, { a: 4 }],
    tree = items[0],
    i = 1,
    j = 0;

while (i < items.length) {
    items[j].left = items[i++];
    if (i >= items.length) break;
    items[j].right = items[i++];
    j++;
}

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly shorte approach.

```js
var items = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 }, { a: 20 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 30 }, { a: 300 }, { a: 40 }, { a: 4 }],
    tree = items[0],
    i = 1,
    side = 'right';

while (i < items.length) {
    side = { left: 'right', right: 'left' }[side];
    items[(i - 1) >> 1][side] = items[i++];
}

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like that you include css in your snippets to maximize the height of the console. This should actually be configurable in the settings of the snippet itself.

Comment: A perfect solution as always

Answer (score 1):

Ok the code is below. This will generate a binary tree as OP mentioned from given `items`. The function will use `while` and `for` loop

## Explanation:

The whole idea is to keep track of the the objects we want to insert new values in an array.

Lets consider we have items array like this

```
var items = [
  { a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 }, { a: 20 }, { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 }, { a: 30 }, { a: 300 }, { a: 40 }, { a: 4 }
]
```

First of all we create an empty object. `obj = {}`. At this point we need to add `.left` and `.right` the `obj`. So we initially set `next = [obj]`.
In the `for` The `.left` and `right` will be added to `obj` as the `next` contains only one element.So the Object loops like this.

```
{
    left:{ a: 1 }, 
    right:{ a: 10 }
}
```

Now in next stop we want to `left` and `right` to both of the keys of current Object. So we push both to `next` array.
So that next Array Looks

```
[{},{ a: 1 },{ a: 10 }]
```

Notice that now `i = 1` So in the next `for` loop `left` and `right` is added to both last elements of array.As elements in array are referencing the properties of object. So this will mutate obj. The `obj`

```
{
    left:{ a: 1,left:{ a: 100 },right:{ a: 20 }},
    right:{ a: 10, right:{ a: 2 },left:{ a: 3 }}
}
```

And now `next` will be be

```
[{},{ a: 1 },{ a: 10 },{ a: 100 },{ a: 20 },{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }]
```

Now in the next loop the next the remain `4` elements will be added to the children of `left` and `right` of `{ a: 100 }` and `{ a: 20 }`. And `items.length` will become `0` and it will `return` the `obj`.

```js
var items = [
  { a: 1 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 100 }, { a: 20 }, { a: 2 },
  { a: 3 }, { a: 30 }, { a: 300 }, { a: 40 }, { a: 4 }
]

function bTree(items){
let obj = {}
let next = [obj];
let i = 0;
while(items.length){
   for(i;i<next.length;i++){      
        next[i].left = items[0]
        next[i].right = items[1]
        items.splice(0,2)
      
        next.push(next[i].left)
        next.push(next[i].right);
        if(!items.length) return obj;
      }
   
   }
}
console.log(bTree(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

@AaditMShah here is a rough iterative one based on what you sent. Thank you.

```js
var items = [ 1, 10, 100, 20, 2, 3, 30, 300, 40, 4 ]
var tree = {}
var node = tree
var stack = [ node ]
var i = 0

while (stack.length) {
  var node = stack.shift()
  node.value = items[i]

  if (node.value) {
    node.left = {}
    stack.push(node.left)
    node.right = {}
    stack.push(node.right)
  }

  i++
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2))
```